# How can i persist the themes that is set by a theme switcher implemented in jquery?

Tags: jquery

my default link tag path pointing to css is

my css paths containing different themes:

```
cssa/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssb/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssc/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssd/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
csse/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
cssf/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
```

Dropdown button implementation of a theme switcher
    boot.html
     Switch Theme

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a data-theme="cssa/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Dark</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="csse/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Apple</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssb/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Blue</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssc/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Pearl</a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a data-theme="cssd/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css">Box</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jquery code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
var link = $('link.me');
 $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var theme = $(this).find('a').data('theme');
     alert(theme)
     link.attr('href', theme)
 });
 });
```

Themes switches perfectly. But if i refresh the page the link tag points back to the default css path to css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css. how can i make the theme to persist even after refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `cookies` to store the values of your preferences. And check for the values in the stored `cookies` to again retrieve your preferred value. Refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for understanding the basics of cookies.

Basic example of cookies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```